# Can the formula of a cell be conditional based on the dropdown selection of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to create a formula where D9 is included/excluded from the formula based on the answer to the dropdown selection of D13 (Financing Repairs? Yes/No)?

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T7Yd9MeGNqE_h9EEwsYfYO_3AqzxVtmAlp5tTdue9oc/edit?usp=sharing)

I've spent hours creating this real estate investment worksheet and just discoved a significant mistake.

Cells H7 (Finance Amount) and H8 (Down Payment Amount) assume the investor is financing the cost of "Repairs/Improvements" (cell D9).

This is not always the case. Sometimes investors finance the property and pay cash for repairs.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The question is an exact copy of [Can the formula of a cell be conditional based on the dropdown selection of another cell?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/202833006). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: +1. Also, while links to external resources, in this case a spreadsheet, might be helpful, please bear in mind that questions in this site should be self contained. Considering this, please assure that the question body includes a description of all the relevant parts of the spreadsheet, some sample data and the corresponding expected result, then this be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the references to `D9` in H7 & H8 with `if(D13="Yes","D9,0)`. This means that if D13 hasn't been marked as 'Yes' then D9 isn't added to the values in H7 or H8.